# The value of my cell will not pull up when locating file in my computer

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently coding a macro in excel and I am having an issue with locating a file in my computer. I need this code to read the value of cell B7 which will be the name of the file in the same folder as this workbook. I need it to open whichever file name is in that cell.

This is the code I have currently and it keeps returning that it can't find the file "sfile" so it is not taking the value from the cell

```
Dim sfile As String
Dim sLink As String

'Get txt from folder
sfile = Worksheets("Instructions").Cells(7, 2).Value

sLink = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "sfile" & ".txt"

'Copy csv to "Unformatted Log" sheet in this workbook
ssheet = "Unformatted Log"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets(ssheet).Cells.ClearContents
Workbooks.Open Filename:=sLink
Windows(sfile).Activate
ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
wnd.Activate
Sheets("Unformatted Log").Select
Range("A1").Select
Sheets("Unformatted Log").Paste
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Windows(sfile).Close False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True'''
```

Comment: What do you get when you use `MsgBox sfile`?

Comment: Remove the quotes around `"sfile"` in `sLink = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "sfile" & ".txt"`.